# Coding theory - Linear application

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, coding-theory

> Show that in a *binary code* either all vectors have *even* weight or half of
>   them have *even* weight and half of them have *odd* weight.

Let $C$ be a binary code and $C \subseteq \mathbb{F}_2^n $. I want to show that all elements of $C$ have weight even or half of the elements of $C$ have weight even.

So I think it's enough to show that the following is a linear application :

$$C \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$$

$$C \rightarrow wt(C) (mod 2)$$

My question on how to prove that this is a linear application?

Comment: This is my first time ever hearing of a "linear application."  I see it elsewhere, but I can't quite tell if it's different from a linear transformation... is there a difference?

Comment: @rschwieb I think it's the same thing. In my language (Portuguese) we say "Aplicação linear" that translating is "Linear aplication". But we can also call it "Transformação linear" that is "Linear transformation"

Comment: Interesting, I did not know. I think you'll avoid puzzled looks in the future by switching to "transformation" in an English forum, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication by scalars is easy, either you multiply by $0$ and the result is $0$ or you multiply by $1$ and nothing changes, so let's focus on additivity.

Given two words $v,w$ consider $v+w$. the weight is just the number of $1$s in the word.

The $i$-th coordinate of $v+w$ is $1$ if either the $i$-th  coordinate of $v$ is $1$ or the $i$-th  coordinate of $w$ is $1$ (yet not both).

Thus the number of $1$s in $v+w$ is is the number of $1$s in $v$ plus the number of $1$s of $w$ minus two times the number of coordinates where both $v$ and $w$ have a $1$.